# Using {% url %} reverse with unicode characters in the parameters (Django)

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django site where one can click on the tags (I use tagulous) of a post to view a list of all posts that use that tag. It works fine, except when the string is unicode. Specifically, it's this line of my template that gives me an error:

```
<a href="{% url 'fortykwords:tag' tag.name %}">{{ tag.name }}</a>
```

It gives me the error

```
Reverse for 'tag' with arguments '('你好',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tag\\/(?P<input_tag>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
```

This is the urls.py:

```
path('tag/<slug:input_tag>', views.tag_view, name='tag'),
```

This is the view from views.py:

```
def tag_view(request, input_tag):
    latest_post_list = Post.objects.filter(tags=input_tag, 
    status__exact="published")
    context = {'latest_post_list': latest_post_list, 'page_tag': input_tag}
    return render(request, 'fortykwords/tag.html', context)
```

What should I change so that I can make reverse of links with unicode arguments?

Comment: does this help? https://djangobook.com/internationalization-url-patterns/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with pattern `\w+` instead of `[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+`.

For that, you need to change `path` to `re_path` to use your own custom regular expression for the url.

**Example**:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    # your regular paths
    path('...'),

    # update to `re_path` for those which can accept unicode letters
    url(r'tag/(?P<input_tag>\w+)$', views.tag_view, name='tag'),
]
```

Comment: But how do I change that? I put <slug:input_tag> , not any pattern.

Comment: Paste the entire line of the url.

Comment: You mean this? `path('tag/<slug:input_tag>', views.tag_view, name='tag')` It's in the question.

Comment: Because it is an old pattern, I had to change "re_path" to "url", but apart from that it works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: How come `re_path` didn't work? I tried it on Django 2.1. Which version are you on?

Comment: 2.0.4.
It said this: 
`?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern 'tag/(?P<input_tag>\w+)$' [name='tag'] has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'. This was likely an oversight when migrating to django.urls.path().`

Comment: It says so when you use `path`, but with `re_path`, the warning goes away. I tried with 2.0.4 version as well.